# MongoDb :Unable to get Collection names in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
 System.out.print("Conencton Successfull");
 List<String> dbs = mongoClient.getDatabaseNames();
 System.out.println(dbs);
 System.out.println("database selected");
 DB db = mongoClient.getDB("ddbb");
 Set<String> collections =  db.getCollectionNames();
 for(String coll : collections){
    System.out.println(coll);
 }
```

Running the above code, gives me the name of database available, but does not output the collection names. I am able to insert document by manually selecting Collection.

OUTPUT:

```
Conencton[admin, ddbb, local]
database selected
```

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old `mongo-java-driver` version? Could you upgrade to a newer version? Not sure if that would fix the problem though.

Comment: Can you change the line `DB db = mongoClient.getDB("ddbb");` to `DB db = mongoClient.getDatabase("ddbb");`

Comment: No it cant be changed to getDatabse()  (no such function). @ Kiran LM.

Comment: Please could you let me know Which is new Mongo driver for java. @ Alex P.

Comment: Do you have any collections in the database?  If there are no collections then the code is functioning correctly.

Comment: Well, [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) you can check for all the versions available, but you'd also need to know what version your MongoDB server is? Could you find out?